# jQuery Drag and Drop image into a background image, web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have search google for drag and drop and I can find alot, but when i look at the ex. code in browser on an iPad/iPhone the drag and drop is not working on em.

do someone here know a solution/tutorial on "drag and drop" that will work on smartphones/Tablets like iPad/iPhone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using jQuery UI for adding drag & drop support, and also including the jQuery UI touch punch plugin to translate touch inputs to 'clicks'.

Good tut for jQuery UI drag & drop:
http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/

touch punch:
http://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch